# How many trees are in an n-cycle? (graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory

I am asked how many trees are in an n-cycle. It doesn't specify that these trees must be spanning trees, just trees. I know the number of trees on n labelled vertices is nexp(n-2), but this isn't necessarily on vertices that form a cycle.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: An $n$-cycle has $n$ edges, so a maximal tree will be a spanning tree in such a graph.  Why not count the number of *paths* of length zero up to $n-1$, if you interpret the problem that way?

Comment: @hardmath a maximal tree is a spanning tree in every graph, in fact.

Comment: @MattS: Heh, yes, at least the connected ones!

Comment: @hardmath Didn't you hear? All graphs are connected now. Forest = tree

Answer (score 0):

Trees are connected graphs that do not contain a cycle. Cycles do not properly contain other cycles, so any proper subgraph of a cycle does not contain a cycle. The goal is therefore to count connected proper subgraphs. For example, subgraphs consisting of two adjacent verices with their adjoining edge are trees; there are $n$ of those. Provided $n>3$, induced subgraphs with three adjacent vertices along the cycle are connected and contain no cycle, and there are $n-1$ of these; etc.

Comment: If we arbitrarily direct the cycle, then a path is determined uniquely by its starting and ending nodes, an ordered pair.  If we include the $0$-length paths (and I see no reason not to), then we get $n^2$ such ordered pairs.  Of course the trees are undirected, but between two distinct nodes there are two paths between them (following different directions around the cycle).